# How do I set Ubuntu as my default OS on a Chromebook?

Tags: boot, chromebook, chromeos

I recently downloaded Ubuntu for my Samsung 5 Chromebook from:

http://cr-48-ubuntu.googlecode.com/files/install-ubuntu-1204-7.sh

Whenever I restart the computer, it goes back to Chrome OS. How can I make it so that it boots into Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Use: `sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 /dev/mmcblk0` for ARM

`sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S q /dev/sda` for Intel Chromebooks

This should set Ubuntu to be the default boot OS.